# Java port of StrictMath.exp?

Tags: math, java

Did anybody port the C source code of StricMath.exp (OpenJDK) to Java and made it available online?

I mean the port of http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/7b641a18cf0b/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/e_exp.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been done: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-375